# Run different Animation on different touches

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, fbx

I've several animations which I want to run on touch of different body parts in unity. Like when arm is being touched , I want to run arm animation and when leg is touched , I want to run leg animation. How I know that which part of body user have touched?

[image]

I assigned tag to different parts and applied switch case to them. But I always get same tag , which is of main base model. Is there any problem in Box collider or in Rig setting?

Comment: To which gameobject is the collider attached to? and post your existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that , I've attached a single collider to main object instead of adding colliders to components of model.